# Incompatible version for gem "activesupport" while installing "threetaps-client" gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activesupport

I'm fairly new to rails and I encountered this gem conflict, while running `bundle install`, between ActiveSupport and threetaps-client (which I need to use for my project).

I tried removing the Gemfile.lock file and running `bundle install` again but it gave me the same error message again. I also tried running `bundle update` which also gave the same result :(

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    activesupport (3.2.13)

  In Gemfile:
    threetaps-client (>= 0) ruby depends on
      activesupport (~> 3.0.0) ruby

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are using Rails 3.2 (and thus, activesupport 3.2).  However, threetaps-client is version locked to rails/activesupport 3.0.x.  The easiest solution to this would be to downgrade Rails to 3.0 in your Gemfile with:

`gem "rails", "~> 3.0"`

And then remove the `Gemfile.lock` and bundle install again.  You should be good to go after that.

**EDIT**

I was able to get the gem to support activesupport 3.2 (I think).  The tests do not pass on this branch, but they did not pass on master either.  I assume this probably has to do with credentials or something.  Update your `Gemfile` to use this repo for `threetaps-client`

```
gem "threetaps-client", git: "git@github.com:ehowe/3taps-Ruby-Client"
```

Insert required "your mileage may vary" warning here.

Comment: That solution is rather tempting but I can't downgrade Rails, or activesupport for that matter. It's just not a feasible solution. Do you know of a way I can work around it?

Comment: revised my answer with another possible solution.

Comment: Ok, so I spoke to the 3Taps devs and they provided me with an alternative solution to access their data. I'll be creating a wrapper class myself and making API calls through that. I did try doing the same thing that you did by forking and changing the gemfile but that didn't work either. I should've mentioned that in the summary. Sorry for the trouble and thanks for the effort. I'll up-vote but won't be accepting your answer since that didn't work.

Comment: Damn, I just realised that I don't have enough rep points to up-vote. That sucks. Well I hope a thank you will do :)